# .NET signature to p/invoke GetSystemDEPPolicy function

Tags: c#, .net, windows, api, pinvoke

I can't find any example signatures for .NET to use this function (GetSystemDEPPolicy).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736298(v=vs.85).aspx

It's a fairly simple function but I don't know how to create the signature to call it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetSystemDEPPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined as

```
DEP_SYSTEM_POLICY_TYPE WINAPI GetSystemDEPPolicy(void);
```

and DEP_SYSTEM_POLICY_TYPE is an enum (see winbase.h assuming you have the C++ components installed in your development environment - if not try [winbase.h](http://source.winehq.org/source/include/winbase.h)) and enums in C default to int, as such I would go with

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern int GetSystemDEPPolicy();
```

May I recommend you follow this tutorial on [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow! GREAT info. I found pinvoke signature generator on [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx) and was just trying to find a copy of winbase.h for Server 2008... I'll give this a try :-)